# Запись NS (name server) указывает на DNS-сервер. Т.е. DNS-сервер сам на себя указывает что ли? Или NS записи лежат где то ещё?

Tags: dns

Ну, по логике, для того чтобы куда то указывать нужна отправная точка из которой мы на что то указываем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ns записи домена указывают, на каком dns сервере лежит подробная информация по домену. 
Насколько я пониманию, ns записи живут на корневых серверах dns. То есть цепочка такова:
Сходить на корневой сервер, получить адрес конечного dns. С него вытащить а запись или что надо. Перейти.

Comment: Так а как они на корневой DNS сервер то попадают? Выходит что NS записи находятся у регистратора.

Comment: Да. А регистратор выгружает их выше

Answer (score 0):

Отправной точкой для доменов второго уровня является регистратор доменных имён, который находится уровнем выше исходного домена. Например инфа о домене example.ru. находится прежде всего в домене .ru. Узнать инфу о нём можно с помощью `whois <домен>`. Можно почитать тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS.

Comment: Т.е. всё таки у регистратора они лежат. Понятно.

Comment: @Hipster для example.ru. путь поиска такой: идём в обратном порядке "." - корневой ДНС, далее "ru.", далее "example."

Comment: Так я спрашивал про другое. Откуда корневой DNS узнаёт о моём DNS сервере? Выходит от регистратора.

Comment: @Hipster, корневой ничего не знает о тебе, он по твоему домену знает только о том, что надо искать в "ru", а "ru" уже знает о том, где "example". Если домен будет host1.example.ru, то "example" в зоне "ru" будет знать о "host1", если он указан в качестве NS

Comment: Зачем вы хотите указать поддомен "host1" в NS записи которая указывает на DNS сервер?

Comment: Так работает ДНС. Это можно, значит нужно понимать, если собираешься использовать.

Comment: NS запись указывает на DNS сервер, а не на мой домен "example".

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Типы_ресурсных_записей_DNS NS-запись указывает на Authoritative name server, им может быть сервер на любом уровне. Если есть нужда указать NS для zone.on.server.example.ru. это всё можно.

Comment: Откуда TDL DNS сервер (например "ru") узнаёт о том, какой DNS у моего сайта "example"?

Comment: Регистратор его регает в зоне ru и указывает там NS-записи.